# How to restrict opening duplicates tab(Dockcontent) using WeifenLuo docking in winforms C#

Tags: c#, winforms, tabs, c#-3.0

I am using `weifenLuo` docking in windows form c#. In this opening image in 1 tab and on button click showing its information and operating functions in another tab. But if I click on that button again(from 1st tab), then it open another tab with same information means duplicate tab.

I dont want to open same tab again, on 2nd button click just want to focus old tab.

[image: Here is picture of tabs]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We use something similar to

```
private IDockContent FindDocument(string text)
{
    foreach (IDockContent content in dockPanel1.Contents)
    {
        if (content.DockHandler.TabText == text)            
                return content;
    }
    return null;
}
```

And check would go something like

```
if (FindDocument(name) == null)
{
    dockContent.Name = name;
    dockContent.TabText = name;
    dockContent.Text = name;
    dockContent.ShowHint = DockState.Document;
    dockContent.Show(dockPanel1);
}
```

Hope this helps